# Java Lab missing detail to get correct answer on Domjudge

Tags: java, eclipse

I had a lab today, the time has already elapsed so it's not like anyone is doing my homework for me... I already got 0. The code I handed in comes back as `wrong answer`, the output I get seems to be the desired output. It's bugging me, I don't know where it is wrong. Can someone please help me find what's wrong? Any help would be appreciated, this is my third time using Java :)

package main;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int COST = 25000;
                
    System.out.print("Enter the balance of your airmiles? "); 
    int airmiles = in.nextInt(); 
    int flights = airmiles/COST;
    int balance = airmiles%COST;
        
    System.out.print("\nYou can redeem "+ flights +" short haul flights. The balance of your air miles will be "+ balance +"."); 
    
        
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

with output:

```
Enter the balance of your airmiles? 76876

You can redeem 3 short haul flights. The balance of your air miles will be 1876.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be good to know that the [DOMjudge team manual](https://www.domjudge.org/docs/manual/master/team.html#code-examples) has code templates that are sure to work. For the next version of DOMjudge, I've made it explicit there not to use any `package` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things might be there:

1. The COST is constant so it should be `static` and `final` and should not be defined in `main`. But this is just a personal choice. Don't know if your instructor took this into consideration while grading.
2. There is an extra space here : `\n You can redeem`. Just after the `\n` and before `You`. So if the output is matched by a program, it is most likely the case that this was leading to the wrong answer.

The output in you case will be: (Notice the extra space)

```
Enter the balance of your airmiles? 76876

 You can redeem 3 short haul flights. The balance of your air miles will be 1876.
```

The code you probably needed was this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab1 {

    static final int COST = 25000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the balance of your airmiles? ");
        int airmiles = in.nextInt();
        int flights = airmiles/COST;
        int balance = airmiles%COST;

        System.out.print("\nYou can redeem "+ flights +" short haul flights. The balance of your air miles will be "+ balance +".");

    }
}
```

The output will now be:

```
Enter the balance of your airmiles? 76876

You can redeem 3 short haul flights. The balance of your air miles will be 1876.
```

Comment: thank you for noticing the extra space, in the end I submitted 5 versions of the code, one without the space and `final` in front of `int COST = 25000` but under `public static void` and it still came up `wrong answer`.

Answer (score 0):

I attended the tutorial today, and spoke with the TA and sent him my code.

I think that the only thing was wrong was `package` declaration at the beginning of the file, apparently I'm not supposed to have that when submitting files on domjudge...